# Validate classification models

Tags: classification, cross-validation, validation, model-evaluation

I have two Naïve Bayes classifiers

```
nb_classifier = MultinomialNB(alpha=0.05, fit_prior=True)
nb_classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

and

```
nb_classifier = MultinomialNB(alpha=1, fit_prior=True)
nb_classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

where the only difference is the alpha value.

How do I choose the classifier that performs best?

I guess I should both classifiers with my test data set, but what should I look for when I claim one of them to be better than the other?

Should I use

```
nb_classifier.score(X_test, y_test)
```

Comment: Have you looked up "cross validation" and "K Fold cross validation"?  There is an entire literature on model selection techniques, and it would be helpful for you to know some basics.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, the classifier that performs the best with your test data is very likely to be the best classifier.

If you want to get more fancy, you can use cross-validation scoring to see if your modes are accurate to similar degrees using different train/test datasets:

```
skl_cv.cross_val_predict(nb_classifier, X = X, y = y, cv = 5)
```

Use your full X and y data, rather than X_train and y_train. The method will split your data into train and test data automatically, and will return an array of scores for each different train/test split. This should help you identify how robust the model is.

Comment: But I don't know what the output means. I just get a vector with a lot of numbers

Comment: then read the documentation, scikit learn has quite a good one

Comment: -1 The test set should not be used for model selection.  Additionally, Xtrain and ytrain are to be used in cross validation, not the entire data set. Without a holdout set, there is no final way to estimate generalization error.